# Travis CI, Xcode - exit command is not passed further when using xcpretty

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, travis-ci, xcodebuild

Here is my `travis.yml` file:

```
osx_image: xcode10.2
language: objective-c

before_install:
- travis_wait 35; cd CalendarKitDemo; pod update

script:
- xcodebuild build -workspace CalendarKitDemo.xcworkspace -scheme "CalendarKitDemo" -sdk iphonesimulator | xcpretty

notifications:
  email: false
```

The problem is that the build is always marked as "succeeded" even if the actual `xcodebuild` command exited with failure, for example, here:
["failing" job that succeeds](https://travis-ci.org/richardtop/CalendarKit/builds/526686878)

[image: succeeding job]

When I remove `xcpretty`, the job passes failure/success correctly, as with [this example job](https://travis-ci.org/richardtop/CalendarKit/builds/526806113).

**How can I both use xcpretty and pass correct values to the Travis CI on the job success / failure?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that bash by default uses the exist code from the last command, in xcpretty. So you get the exist code from xcpretty.

You can either go and set the pipefail in your environment (set -o pipefail).

`pipefail` will cause the script to exit with the first non-zero exit code.

E.g. in your Travis file

```
script:
- set -o pipefail
- xcodebuild build -workspace CalendarKitDemo.xcworkspace -scheme "CalendarKitDemo" -sdk iphonesimulator | xcpretty
```

If you want to be more explicit you can also get the exitcode from the first command (xcodebuild) bash exposes the exit codes of a pipeline in the `PIPESTATUS` array.

So e.g.

`- xcodebuild build -workspace CalendarKitDemo.xcworkspace -scheme "CalendarKitDemo" -sdk iphonesimulator | xcpretty && exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}"`

Comment: Could you please provide also the example with "pipefail"?

Comment: @RichardTopchiy if my answer was useful, do you mind accepting it as the correct answer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, works perfectly and sorry for the late reply!